# Set java variable from gradle script

Tags: android, gradle

I have an android library project (using android studio IDE).
I want to create two version of the deliverable jar, a debug version and a release version.

The debug version will have log level set to verbose and release version will have it set to silent.
The verbose vs silent is based on an integer variable in a .java file.

I want to set this variable to verbose while generating debug version and want to set it to silent for release version using gradle.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `build.gradle` you can specifiy custom buildConfigFields.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        buildConfigField "String", "LOG_LEVEL", "\"silent\""
    }

    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "LOG_LEVEL", "\"verbose\""          
    }
}
```

These will then be available as `BuildConfig.LOG_LEVEL` when you compile.

Though you might be better of just checking the already available `BuildConfig.DEBUG`.